# how to make dynamic input inside form tag with reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular10

I am trying to make a reactive form with dynamic input

so I created the reactive form component like this

**main_component.ts**

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.operationGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'operation': '',
      'searchTerm': ''
    });

  }
```

**main_component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="operationGroupForm">
     <input type="text" formControlName="operation">
     <div operationClass [type]="'mycustomtype'"
     [_formControlName]="'searchTerm'"></div>
     </div>
</form>
```

and created the directive `operationClass` that appended to the div and inject the component into the `div`

**operationClass.directive.ts**

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer2, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactory: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
      var comRef = this.componentFactory.resolveComponentFactory(input_component);
      var _comRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(comRef);
      _comRef.instance.formControlName = this._formControlName;
      _comRef.instance.type = this.type;
}
```

and that component renders the right input by taking the `formControlName` and `type` and rendering the input on the custom condition

and that component for rendering input is :
**input_component.ts**

```
  @Input() formControlName: string;
  @Input() type: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

**input_component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="type">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="type">
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'mycustomtype'">
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="formControlName" class="form-control" />
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
      <input type="number" [formControlName]="formControlName" class="form-control" />
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

the problem is that as I think the inner input `formControlName` can't see the outer `formGroup` because it generates that error

```
ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it to an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

      Example:

      
    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });
    at Function.controlParentException (forms.js:1692)
    at FormControlName._checkParentType (forms.js:6059)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6063)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:5995)
    at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:2131)
    at callHook (core.js:3042)
    at callHooks (core.js:3008)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2960)
    at refreshView (core.js:7331)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8408)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider applying to your code the following changes:

**main_component.ts**

> The value for each control name is an array containing the initial value as the first item in the array. ([Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#using-the-formbuilder-service-to-generate-controls))

```js
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.operationGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'operation': [''], // <== provide an array
    'searchTerm': [''] // <== provide an array
  });
}
```

**input_component.ts**

Since `formControlName` must be used with a parent `formGroup` directive you'll want to add a `formGroup` directive and pass it your `formGroup` instance, rather than passing your `formGroup` instance along you can inject it in your child component using [ControlContainer](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlContainer) as demonstrated below:

```js
import { FormGroup, ControlContainer } from '@angular/forms';

...

@Input() formControlName: string;
@Input() type: string;
 public formGroup: FormGroup;

constructor(public controlContainer: ControlContainer) { // <== inject reference to formGroup via ElementInjector
  this.formGroup = controlContainer.control as FormGroup
}
```

**input_component.html**

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="type">
  <ng-container [ngSwitch]="type" [formGroup]="formGroup"> <!-- <== pass injected form -->
    <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'mycustomtype'">
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="formControlName" class="form-control" />
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
      <input type="number" [formControlName]="formControlName" class="form-control" />
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

[For further information about FormContainer](https://jenniferwadella.com/blog/angular-control-container)

Comment: thanks alot. but can you explain that line please ```this.formGroup = controlContainer.control as FormGroup ``` and what is **controlContainer** and how it know that to take the **operationGroupForm** where is the link, and if there is another formgroup which one will it take. but in general thanks alot.

Comment: i've faced another problem and the inner formgroup is seperated than the outer group. when change the data in the inner form it's not change its value in the outer form subscriber.

Comment: `@Hassan Ahmed` make sure you don't reassign `operationGroupForm` a hew instance of FormControl, is that the case?

Comment: `@Hassan Ahmed`what do you mean by "inner formGroup"

Comment: ```@Rafi Heing``` the form group in **input_component**

Comment: make sure you don't reassign operationGroupForm a hew instance of FormControl

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are missing the `FormGroup` directive and instantiation in the component and class where the control is used, i.e. *input.component.{ts|html}*.

Something like:

```
this.myFormGroup = new FormGroup({
   formControlName: new FormControl()
});
```

See the section [Create a FormGroup instance](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) from the Angular documentation.

Comment: its right here ```this.operationGroupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'operation': '',
      'searchTerm': ''
    });```